Необходимо вывести только тот массив, в котором есть совпадение с переменной


const name = 'Sydorenko'
const arr = [
  ['Азаров'],
  ['Сидоренко', 'Sydorenko'],
  ['Хоменко']
]

const res = arr.map(item => {
  for (const elem of item) {
    if (elem === name) {
      return item
    }
  }
})
console.log(res)




Map возвращает тот же массив, не меньше и не больше, но возможно с другими значениями. И в вашем случае это бесполезный перебор - в результате вы получали тот же массив с undefined и целевым массивом.
Поэтому лучше использовать reduce c первоначальным значением [], при переборе проверять наличие includes и добавлять в итоговый при совпадении. При этом если нужен одноуровневый массив - развернуть при добавлении acc.push(...item), или не разворачивать - если нужен массив массивов.


const name = 'Sydorenko'
const arr = [
  ['Азаров'],
  ['Сидоренко', 'Sydorenko'],
  ['Хоменко']
]

const res = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.includes(name)) acc.push(...item);
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(res)




По-моему, вы сильно усложнили решение. Есть filter как раз для этого: arr.filter(lst => lst.includes(name))

@Алексей Р - что бы получить массив с 1м значением массива? - да фильтр лучше, а чтобы сразу развернуть - то reduce удобнее.
